# Performance: While Loop with AWK

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I have a file that I want to import into a database table, but I want to have a piece in each row. In the import, I need to indicate for each row the offset (first byte) and length (number of bytes)

I have the following files:

```
*line_numbers.txt* -> Each row contains the number of 
                      the last row of a record in *plans.txt*.

*plans.txt* ->  All the information required for all the rows.
```

I have the following code:

```
#Starting line number of the record
sLine=0

#Starting byte value of the record
offSet=0

while read line
do
    endByte=`awk -v fline=${sLine} -v lline=${line} \
                 '{if (NR > fline && NR < lline) \
                      sum += length($0); } \
                 END {print sum}' plans.txt`
    echo "\"plans.txt.${offSet}.${endByte}/\"" >> lobs.in
    sLine=$((line+1))
    offSet=$((endByte+offSet))
done < line_numbers.txt
```

This code will write in the file *lobs.in* something similar to:

```
"plans.txt.0.504/"
"plans.txt.505.480/"
"plans.txt.984.480/"
"plans.txt.1464.1159/"
"plans.txt.2623.515/"
```

This means, for example, that the first record starts at byte *0* and continues for the next *504* bytes. The next starts at byte *505* and continues for the next *480* bytes.

I still have to run more tests, but It seems to be working.
My problem is It is very very slow for the volume I need to process.

Do you have any performance tips?

I looked in a way to insert the loop in `awk`, but I need 2 input files and I don't know how to process It without the while.

Thank you!

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons not to manipulate text with a shell loop. Just use awk. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this all in `awk` would be much faster.

Suppose you have:

```
$ cat lines.txt
100
200
300
360
10000
50000
```

And:

```
$ awk -v maxl=50000 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=maxl;i++) printf "Line %d\n", i}' >data.txt
```

(So you have `Line 1\nLine 2\n...Line maxl` in the file `data.txt`)

You would do something like:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{lines[FNR]=$1; next}
            {data[FNR]=length($0); next}
     END{ sl=1
          for (i=1; i in lines; i++) {
               bc=0
               for (j=sl; j<=lines[i]; j++){
                   bc+=data[j]
               }
               printf "line %d to %d is %d bytes\n", sl, j-1, bc
               sl=lines[i]+1
          }    
}' lines.txt data.txt
line 1 to 100 is 1392 bytes
line 101 to 200 is 1500 bytes
line 201 to 300 is 1500 bytes
line 301 to 360 is 900 bytes
line 361 to 10000 is 153602 bytes
line 10001 to 50000 is 680000 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple improvement.  Never redirect *inside* a loop with `>>`, what can be redirected outside a loop with `>>`.  Worse:

```
while read line
do
    # .... stuff omitted ... 
    echo "\"plans.txt.${offSet}.${endByte}/\"" >> lobs.in
    # ....
done < line_numbers.txt
```

Note how the only line in the loop that outputs anything is `echo`.  Better:

```
while read line
do
    # .... stuff omitted ... 
    echo "\"plans.txt.${offSet}.${endByte}/\""
    # ....
done < line_numbers.txt >> lobs.in
```

Comment: Don't assume `lobs.in` is empty prior to the loop; use `>>` outside the loop as well.